# Any way to loop through all tables in a dataset in a BigQuery standard SQL script?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have many daily tables (named by _YYYYMMDD suffix) in a dataset. I need to write a daily Scheduled Query to loop through each daily table, perform a join with another dynamically changing table, and overwrite that day's table all in BigQuery. I was looking into "Scripting in standard SQL" and wondered if there might be a way to iterate over _YYYYMMDD tables in a loop?

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use Wildcard tables, which allows you to use some features in Standard SQL with BigQuery. You can read more and see some examples [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/wildcard-table-reference).

Furthermore, the syntax you are looking for should be similar to this:

```
SELECT 
#columns that you want
FROM
  `<project-id>.<dataset-id>.<table-prefix>*`
```

The asterisk represents which tables the select will scan, in this case every table with the same prefix. On the other hand, you can also use **_TABLE_SUFFIX** to restrict scans of your tables, you can read more bout it [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables). Also, below there is a sample of how it would look like:

```
SELECT
  ROUND((max-32)*5/9,1) celsius
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod19*`
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX = (SELECT SUBSTR(MAX(table_id), LENGTH('gsod19') + 1)
      FROM `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.__TABLES_SUMMARY__`
      WHERE table_id LIKE 'gsod194%')
```

I hope it helps.

***ANSWER UPDATE (after user comments):***

There is a method called [UPDATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/updating-data) in BigQuery, which allows the user upodate data from certain columns inside a dataset. In you case that might be a appropriate solution. The syntax for using update is as follows:

```
UPDATE sample_db.UserSessions
SET ip_address = REGEXP_REPLACE(ip_address, r"(\.[0-9]+)$", ".0")
WHERE TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Sorry if this wasn't clear from my question: the current dataset consists of wildcard tables broken up by the _YYYYMMDD prefix. So example:
dataset_20200101, dataset_20200102 etc.
My requirement is: to take each individual daily table from these nested wildcard tables, perform a join with another table (that updates every day), and overwrite the original table with this new table. I need to perform this on 60+ wildcard tables and wondered if there was any easy way to loop through multiple wildcard tables parameterising on YYYYMMDD.

Comment: P.S. I am also able to write a little bit of Python code to help with this (in terms of tools currently using pandas_gbq but plan to migrate to BigQuery Python Client Library). So if there's a cost-effective way to accomplish this via a Python Cloud Function that would also be interesting to hear.

Comment: @mrag, whe you  say "overwrite the original table", which table is this? You have daily tables with a timestamp suffix and a table which will be uploaded by these table values. Did I get it right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. So there are two tables in the same dataset. One "table" consists of 60+ nested wildcard tables with _YYYMMDD suffix. Other table contains a single table. Both are updated each day independently of each other. I need to take each individual _YYYYMMDD table from first table, join with second table, and overwrite the first _YYYYMMDD table. Hopefully that's clearer. Sorry about the confusion. Ideally, I would just update relevant rows that are affected each day but since BigQuery does not allow updating individual rows I have to delete & replace entire tables.

Comment: @mrag, thanks for your reply. I was going to ask you that, do you really need to overwrite everything? Because there is an UPDATE method in BigQuery where you can update columns of you data set. Link: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/updating-data

Comment: @mrag, have you seem the UPDATE method I referred above?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to respond yesterday, yes that was helpful. Thank you for sharing that information.

Comment: @mrag, I will update the answer. I would appreciate if you can accept the answer and upvote it.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I am relatively new to Stackoverflow, how do I accept the answer and upvote it? I've glanced through the BigQuery UPDATE documentation. A quick question about the BigQuery UPDATE statement, can I use to change individual column values for specific rows? Example, I want to update [value1] to [value2] for {column1} only for the rows where {column1} = [value1]. How could I do something like this? Thanks

Comment: Would it be something like:

UPDATE tableName.column1
SET column1 = value2
WHERE columns1 = value1

Comment: I think DML (including UPDATE) over wildcard nested tables may not be supported...

Comment: @mrag, I just saw that are limitations for wildcard table and update method. LINK: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#limitations. I will check if thre are any alternative methods. Also, here is another question which explains how to accept an answer for your knowledge. Link:https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168142/how-to-accept-and-upvote-resource-for-new-users

Comment: Did you manage to work with one of the methods I suggested to you?

Comment: I thought you were going to check to see if there were any workarounds to the limitation of using DML for wildcard tables?

Comment: I could not find any workaround for DML with Wildcards table. You can use wildcard tables only in the FROM inside a UPDATE statement.